# how to prevent mouseover effect not disppearing after mouseleave

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I am trying to do mouseover and show thumb effect, this is the example code:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="">testing</a></li>
   <li><a href="">testing</a></li>
   <li><a href="">testing</a></li>
   <li><a href="">testing</a></li>
   <li><a href="">testing</a></li>
   <li><a href="">testing</a></li> 
   <img class="img" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="display:none">
</ul>
```

Js script:

```
$('li').hover(
  function(e){
    $('.img').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left': e.pageX,
        'top': e.pageY
    }).fadeIn();
},
  function(e){
    $('.img').hide();
});
```

the demo can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/8zG2Q/2/,

the problem is when mouse over the item quickly, the image does not hide after mouse leaves all the items. I have tried use show() instead of fadeIn(), but this does not help because I load the image from server, it takes time to be visible.

so what could be a nice solution to hide the image whenever mouse is out of all itmes? thanks for help.

Comment: works fine for me (i.e. image disappears if I mouseout regardless of how quick I'm hovering over them)

Comment: It was using show(), try to see the demo again.

Comment: You can try using .animate() to achieve this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805906/jquery-stop-fadein-fadeout

Comment: @andreas, thanks, let me try that.

Comment: that does not seem to help. thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `fadeIn()`, stop the animation (optionally clearing the queue and also jumping to the end of the animation) then hide the element (resetting to the 'base state'), like so:

```
$('li').hover(
  function(e){
    $('.img').css({
        'position':'absolute',
        'left': e.pageX,
        'top': e.pageY
    }).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn();
},
  function(e){
    $('.img').hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi,cheeken, thanks for your answer, this does not work in my case, the image still hanging there when the mouse quickly hover out.

Comment: oh, I see it works for the example I posted here, you deserve some credit for that, but my case is loading image from server, so it does not work this way. but this is a good inspiration.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem.  What browser are you using?