# jQuery mouse enter

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

**EDIT**

The problem I had was the overlay had a higher z-index than the '.bar' element. 
Thanks to @nnnnnn for pointing out the obvious!

On the site I am creating I want an overlay to fade in when the user hovers over an element and to fade out when they leave the element.

The code I am using so far is:

```
$(".bar").mouseenter(function() {
$('#overlay_hover').fadeIn('slow');
})

$(".bar").mouseleave(function() {
$('#overlay_hover').fadeOut('slow');
})
```

This works to fadeIn the overlay but when I add the second piece of code to fadeOut when you hover over '.bar' the overlay fades in and out repeatedly. I'm sure it's simple but I'm just starting out with jQuery, any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the overlay element appear over the top of the `.bar` element?

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn, it's so obvious now that this was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

you could use .stop()

for example

```
$('#overlay_hover').stop().fadeOut('slow');
```

jQuery reference http://api.jquery.com/stop/

also have a look here
[Jquery Stop Fadein / Fadeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805906/jquery-stop-fadein-fadeout)

Comment: OP said "when you hover over '.bar' the overlay fades in and out repeatedly", he didn't say "when you move the mouse in and out several times while the previous animation is running it fades in and out several times".

Answer (score 0):

Or you may try to use,

```
$(".bar").on("mouseenter", "div", function(){
    $('#overlay_hover').fadeIn('slow');
}).on("mouseleave", "div", function(){
    $('#overlay_hover').fadeOut('slow');
});
```