# jquery mouseover / mouseout probel

Tags: jquery

I have small problem with fading some element.
It's my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7uXtw/

When you hover on black square then appear grey square and text "some text"
When you mouseleave everything should go to the start state.

The main problem concer the fast mouseover and mouseleave on the square. Then the text "some text" don't fadeOut. How can I change my code to fix this bug?

I used `.stop()` but it don't resolve the problem

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805906/jquery-stop-fadein-fadeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hide dat overflow**

I just added `overflow:hidden` to `a` in the css, and it seems to work great.

`.info_text` is larger than its `a` parent, so `mouseleave` wont fire until you've cleared it.

**jquery**
*this config of stop and stop(true,true) seems to do the trick*

```
$("#options_down li").delegate('a','mouseover mouseleave', function(e){
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {//on mouseover
        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({ top: '+36px'},100).end()//img down
        .find(".info").stop().animate({ height: '136', opacity: 0.8 }, 100).end()//info out
        .find('.info_text').stop(true,true).delay(100).fadeIn(100).end()//infotext in
        .find('.info p, .info h3').stop().fadeOut(100);//hide innards
    } else if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {//on mouseleave
        $(this).find("img").stop(true,true).animate({ top: '0px' },100).end()//img up
        .find(".info").stop(true,true).animate({ height: '40', opacity: 1 }, 100).end()//info in
        .find('.info_text').stop().fadeOut(100).end()//infotext out
        .find('.info p, .info h3').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);//show innards
    }
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/rb48W/