# Fade in/out on mouseenter/mouseleave, stop queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the snippet I'm using to make some images change their src on hover.

```
$(".social").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).data("original-src", $(this).attr("src"))
            .fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("original-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

There an issue, when you pass the mouse over multiple times, the animation is repeated and the queue goes crazy.. see this video: http://youtu.be/dTYhbcQM3tI
How can I avoid that? I tried with `.stop()` but doesn't seem to be working properly.

Here's the base JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/925/

Comment: SVG icons and a bit of CSS could save you a lot of headache.

Comment: it seems like this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805906/jquery-stop-fadein-fadeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stop(true, true)` (clear the queue? true, jump to the end? true)

```
$(".social").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).data("original-src", $(this).attr("src"))
            .stop(true, true).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("original-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the animation queue as soon as you mouseenter and then create animations again. Much like this:

```
$(".social").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).finish();
        $(this).data("original-src", $(this).attr("src"))
            .fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("original-src"));
        }).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```